# Time column interval filter

Tags: pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe with a "Fecha" column, I would like to reduce de Dataframe size through filter it and maintain just the rows which are on each 10 minutes multiple and discard all rows which are not in 10 minutes multiple.

**[image: Desired filter]**

Some idea?
Thanks

Comment: You need to provide at least on what technology you are working on, how the table is generated and most importantly: share the relevant code. Otherwise, we cannot help you.

Comment: Sure,
this is a Pandas Dataframe from a CSV read. I do not have an specific code due to all data is contained on the CSV.
May be I could generate a  data frame with a column with dates and thus use it such as example for my question.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve) and have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I have to guess some variable names. But assuming your dataframe name is df, the solution should look similar to:

```
df['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Fecha'])
df = df[df['Fecha'].minute % 10 == 0]
```

The first line guarantees that your 'Fecha' column is in DateTime-Format. The second line filters all rows which are a multiple of 10 minutes. To do this you use the modulus operator %.

Since I'm not sure if this solves your problem, here's a minimal example that runs by itself:

```
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp(2020, 1, 1), periods=60, freq='1T')
series = pd.Series(1, index=idx)
series = series[series.index.minute % 10 == 0]
series
```

The first three lines construct a series with a 1 minute index, which is filtered in the fourth line.

Output:

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00    1
2020-01-01 00:10:00    1
2020-01-01 00:20:00    1
2020-01-01 00:30:00    1
2020-01-01 00:40:00    1
2020-01-01 00:50:00    1
dtype: int64
```